# С++: Проблема с перегрузкой оператора в классе

Tags: c++, объекты

Изучаю книгу по С++ и играюсь с перегрузкой операторов.

Следующий код без перегрузки операторов operator FirstMainPart() и operator  SecondMainPart() компилируется и работает, но с ней компилятор выдает ошибку:

> cpp_book4.cpp: In member function 'MainObject::operator
> FirstMainPart()': cpp_book4.cpp:23:3: error: return type 'class
> FirstMainPart' is incomplete    {    ^ cpp_book4.cpp:24:34: error:
> invalid use of incomplete type 'class FirstMainPart'
> return new FirstMainPart(this);
> ^ cpp_book4.cpp:4:7: note: forward declaration of 'class FirstMainPart'  class FirstMainPart;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

И дальше про второй объект то же самое, хотя объявление данных классов вначале программы есть.

```
#include <iostream>


class FirstMainPart;
class SecondMainPart;

class MainObject {
public:
  MainObject() {}
  
  void get_first()
  {
    std::cout << "First" << std::endl;
  }

   void get_second()
  {
    std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;
  }
  

  operator FirstMainPart() { return new FirstMainPart(this); }

  operator SecondMainPart() { return new SecondMainPart(this); }
};


class FirstMainPart {
private:
  MainObject * obj;
public:
  FirstMainPart() {}
  FirstMainPart (MainObject * _obj) : obj(_obj) {}
  void print_first()
  {
    obj->get_first();
  }

};


class SecondMainPart {
private:
  MainObject * obj;
public:
  SecondMainPart (MainObject * _obj) : obj(_obj) {}
  void print_second()
  {
    obj->get_second();
  }
};

int main()
{
  MainObject * o = new MainObject;

 

  
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вот так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


class FirstMainPart;
class SecondMainPart;

class MainObject {
public:
    MainObject() {}

    void get_first()
    {
        std::cout << "First" << std::endl;
    }

    void get_second()
    {
        std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;
    }


    operator FirstMainPart();

    operator SecondMainPart();
};


class FirstMainPart {
private:
    MainObject * obj;
public:
    FirstMainPart() {}
    FirstMainPart(MainObject * _obj) : obj(_obj) {}
    void print_first()
    {
        obj->get_first();
    }

};


class SecondMainPart {
private:
    MainObject * obj;
public:
    SecondMainPart(MainObject * _obj) : obj(_obj) {}
    void print_second()
    {
        obj->get_second();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MainObject * o = new MainObject;




    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


MainObject::operator FirstMainPart() 
{ 
    return FirstMainPart(this); 
}


MainObject::operator SecondMainPart() 
{ 
    return SecondMainPart(this); 
}
```

1. Убрал `new` из операторов
2. Перенёс определения операторов в самый низ, в классе оставил только объявления. (Недаром так советуют делать во всех учебниках).

Теперь о причинах ошибок:

Написав вверху

```cpp
class FirstMainPart;
class SecondMainPart;
```

Вы "рассказали" компилятору, что такие классы есть. И всё. "Ни слова" об их составе и поведении, в том числе и об аргументах конструктора.

Далее Вы вызываете конструкторы этих классов в операторах класса `MainObject`. И передаёте конструкторам аргументы. Но на этом моменте компилятор ещё "не дочитал" до полноценного описания конструкторов, а потому понятия не имеет, какие аргументы эти конструкторы принимают, не удалены ли они вообще и т.д. Потому и ругается.

Первое решение, пришедшее в голову, – поместить определения классов `FirstMainPart` и `SecondMainPart` выше определения класса `MainObject`, чтобы из операторов было "видно" информацию о конструкторах. Но тут возникает проблема. В этих двух классах используются методы класса `MainObject`, которых, опять же, "не видно", потому что они описаны ниже.

А значит, остаётся то, что я и сделал – поместить определения методов-операторов в самый низ или, по крайней мере, ниже определения классов `FirstMainPart` и `SecondMainPart`. В таком случае, когда компилятор дойдёт до этих операторов, он уже успеет "прочитать" выше о конструкторах нужных классов и их аргументах. При этом сам класс `MainObject`, как и его методы `get_first()` и `get_second()` будут объявлены над кассами `FirstMainPart` и `SecondMainPart`, что позволит беспрепятственно их вызвать.

P.S. Совет на будущее – разделяйте объявления и определения членов класса. Книжки по С++ плохого, как правило, не советуют.

Comment: Спасибо. А почему new нужно убрать?

Comment: Возвращаемое значение такого оператора – `FirstMainPart`. А `new` возвращает `FirstMainPart *`.